# Incremential operation with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a function for my database using Cloud Functions for Firebase. The purpose of the function is to listen to write events on the `attend` table and based on the object written to identify the event and increment the `usersAttending` on the event object.

This is my function so far.

```
//listens to write on attendObjects (when a user is attending an event), and increments attending users for event 
exports.listenAttendingEvents = functions.database.ref('/attend/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {

//get attendObj -> parsed JSON by javascript interpreter
const attentObj = event.data.val();
const attendId = attentObj['attendId'];
const pathToAttendees = '/attends' + '/' + attendId;

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
 admin.database().ref(pathToAttendees).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  const obj = snapshot.val();
    var nrAttending = obj['attending'];
         nrAttending = Number(snapshot.val());
         return admin.database().ref(pathToAttendees + '/attending').transaction(function (nrAttending) {
             return (nrAttending || 0) + 1;
        }); 
    });
}, function (errorObject) {
   console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
   return errorObject
});
```

The problems as it seems is that the `event object` doesn't get retrieved. The function seems to finish before that with the status `ok`

Comment: You'e not returning a promise from your top-level function, which means Google Cloud Functions may kill it while the asynchronous database transaction is still in progress. Read this page in the docs for more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ... thank you a lot ... always helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not having a promise for my top-level function. This caused Google Cloud Functions to kill it before the operation was complete.

Adding a promise solved my problem

```
admin.database().ref(pathToAttendees).once("value").then( function(snapshot) {
```